# Parse list of connected vertices from polygon triangles

Tags: javascript, polygon, vertex

[image]

I have:

- An array of vertices at with its position {x,y}
- An array of triangles with its vertices {a,b,c} (elements are integers that refer to the index of the desired vertex in the vertex array)

The array of vertices is sorted incorrectly. As you can see, vertex 9 connects with 11, which goes to 13, which goes to 17, etc.

So what I need is a list of the desired array, going around the perimeter. In the above image's case this would be:
`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,17,16,15,19,21,22,23,25,27,29,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,28,26,24,20,18,14,12,10`

I've noticed that lines that repeat themselves are the ones I need to filter out. For example, 9 to 15 happens twice. I need to keep only those that occur once and sort them properly.

I've had a go at it but did not get very far, and it feels extremely messy. It results in an array containing lines, which are unsorted.

```
var order = [faces[i], faces[i+1], faces[i+2]];
order.sort(function sortNumber(a,b){return a - b});
var names = [order[0]+":"+order[1], order[0]+":"+order[2], order[1]+":"+order[2]];
for(var k in names){
    if(paths.indexOf(names[k]) > -1)
        doubles.push(names[k]);

    paths.push(names[k]);
}
paths = paths.filter(function(el){
  return doubles.indexOf(el) < 0;
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to include ``26`` in the perimeter list? If so, I'm confused what you're asking for.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I thought I saw a line between ``28`` and ``24``. My mistake.

Comment: You're looking for an algorithm to construct a convex hull, I believe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the [blue polygon on this image](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~beezer/cs507/mygifs/figure3.gif) is a convex hull? That's not what I'm going for.

Comment: I guess this question is related with [this other question in gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99353/vertex-ordering-with-threejss-exporter/101175#101175). I answered it, including example of code (C#). I don't know it that helps, and if I should answer here too...